# OpenCV+Java: Zero faces detected when run from jar

Tags: java, opencv, clojure

I'm working on a project using OpenCV for Java from clojure, specifically installed from maven using https://github.com/PatternConsulting/opencv. However, for some reason when I package the app into a jar and run it, I detect 0 faces in every image, even though they worked when it was run in debug mode (though `lein run`).

Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. OpenCV could not read the xml classifiers from resources embedded in the jar. I moved the xml files to the root of the project and loaded them from there and it works.